# From a DataFrame how do I get the column name for the column that has the max value

Tags: python, dataframe, max

If I have a DataFrame with numeric values in it, how do I determine which column contains the max value?

|  | EEM_X | EFA_X | QQQ_X | SPY_X |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 126 | 0.1898 | 0.1490 | 0.1025 | 0.0965 |
| 127 | 0.1911 | 0.1476 | 0.0678 | 0.0793 |
| 128 | 0.1986 | 0.1590 | 0.0750 | 0.0893 |
| 129 | 0.2180 | 0.1703 | 0.0783 | 0.0924 |

I want to add a new column ['MAX'] that contains the column name where the value in each row is the highest.

Comment: I was trying something like this

df['MAX'] = df[df.columns[-4:]].max()

And I got this message return and my df with NaN's in the MAX column
<ipython-input-84-830f7692b47e>:2: SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

See the caveats in the documentation: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy
  df4['MAX'] = df4[df4.columns[-3:]].max()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This shoud work:

```
df.apply(pd.Series.idxmax, axis=1)
```

Comment: That worked, but I do get this warning

<ipython-input-90-4b37c4e8fd03>:2: SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

See the caveats in the documentation: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy
  df['MAX'] = df.apply(pd.Series.idxmax, axis=1)

Comment: That's probable because df is a subset of another DataFrame. Try to do a copy before create new vars on a Dataframe that is a subset of another. 

`df = anotherdf.copy()`